# How to stop ReSharper from adding blank lines in my C# structs?

Tags: c#, resharper

I want my structs to look like this:

```
struct Credentials
{
    public string Username;
    public string Password;
}
```

ReSharper insists on putting a blank line after the "{" and another before the "}". Is there an option I can turn off (or on) so that I can get the look I want without having to go back and delete ReSharper's blank lines?

Comment: You have turned off automatic line breaking in visual studio, I guess?

Comment: As an aside - mutable structs, and public fields? Nooooooo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into `ReSharper -> Options -> Code Editing -> C# -> Blank Lines` and edit according to your preferences.

At least for R# 9+.

Comment: I looked there before posting. Nothing about structs in there. And I tried other items to no avail.

Comment: Have you verified that "Inside type" is set to 0? (struct is a type). Otherwise, are you sure that this is R# behavior and not coming from somewhere else?

Comment: That was it, Marcus! Thank you.